# React-router v4: how to position a rendered component from router?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a sub router set up:

```
class FrontPage extends Component {

    return(
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to='/frontpage/album'><img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7bzZROFhtMUNCdHM" className={styles.photoSize} /></Link>

        <div>
        <Route path='/frontpage/album' component={Album}/>
        </div>

      </div>
      </Router>

      )
  }

}

export default FrontPage;
```

What I have trouble is trying to render the Album component at the top of the page instead of the bottom when the image is clicked. How can I make it so that when a user clicks on the image, the album component will show at the top of the page instead of bottom of the picture?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I havn't tried anything else besides what I have here. There is no errors, I'm just trying to render a component to a position I want. Right now when the user clicks on the image, the album shows below the image. Instead of the album rendering below the image, how do I render the album at the top of the image?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I figured it out, I just needed to move the route for Album above Link, so that it renders at the top of the image when users click on image.